# CXF BusException No DestinationFactory for namespace http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf, jax-rs

I'm trying to stand up the [basic cxf rs example][1], but with my own service `impl` which is even simpler and all my methods return strings.  When I try to run this server I get this exception

I built a clean project so I'm starting fresh..

Master pom
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<name>Tests</name>
<groupId>com.crush</groupId>
<artifactId>tests</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <cxf.version>2.7.11</cxf.version>
    <httpclient.version>3.1</httpclient.version>
    <rs-api.version>2.0</rs-api.version>

    <disclaimer/>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <slf4j.version>1.6.2</slf4j.version>
    <guava.version>13.0-rc2</guava.version>
    <jgroups.version>3.1.0.Final</jgroups.version>
    <infinispan.version>5.1.4.CR1</infinispan.version>
    <commons.cli.version>1.2</commons.cli.version>
    <jettison.version>1.3.2</jettison.version>
    <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <bouncycastle.version>1.46</bouncycastle.version>
    <junit.version>4.8</junit.version>
    <jasypt.version>1.9.0</jasypt.version>

    <!-- Additional Dependencies -->
    <cxf.buildtools.version>2.2.12</cxf.buildtools.version>

    <!-- Maven Plugin Versions -->
    <shade.plugin.version>1.7.1</shade.plugin.version>
    <buildnumber.plugin.version>1.1</buildnumber.plugin.version>
    <jar.plugin.version>2.4</jar.plugin.version>
    <resources.plugin.version>2.5</resources.plugin.version>
    <versions.plugin.version>1.3.1</versions.plugin.version>

    <!-- Plugin Versions -->
    <compiler.plugin.version>2.4</compiler.plugin.version>
    <surefire.plugin.version>2.12.4</surefire.plugin.version>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    <jboss.cache.version>3.2.5.GA</jboss.cache.version>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd-HHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>sample-service</module>
</modules>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- This dependency is needed if you're using the Jetty container -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>${rs-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- This plugin is used update the version numbers of the project
                    during the release process. -->
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${versions.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Plugin configuration for the plugin that specifies the base file encoding. -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${resources.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

sample-service pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-    v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.crush</groupId>
    <artifactId>tests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>sample-service</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Simple CXF project using spring configuration</name>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<profiles>
        <profile>
              <id>server</id>
            <build>
                <defaultGoal>test</defaultGoal>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>java</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <mainClass>com.crush.tests.service.Test</mainClass>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.crush.tests.service.Test</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: crush
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_55

### Main-Class: com.crush.tests.service.Test

SampleServiceImpl

```
package com.crush.tests.service.ws.impl;

import javax.jws.WebService;

import com.crush.tests.service.ws.SampleService;

import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
impo rt javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.crush.tests.service.ws.SampleService")
@Path("/sample/")
@Produces("text/xml")
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService
{
public SampleServiceImpl()
{

}

@GET
@Path("/hi/{text}")
public String sayHi(@PathParam("text") String text)
{
    return "Hello " + text;
}


}
```

When I run this with: mvn -Pserver
Jun 27, 2014 3:10:26 PM org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl initDestination
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be http ://localhost:9000/
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Server ready...

Like I was before, and running from the bundled jar
java -cp sample-service-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.crush.tests.service.Test
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:205)
    at com.crush.tests.service.Test.(Test.java:25)
    at com.crush.tests.service.Test.main(Test.java:30)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.BusException: No DestinationFactory was found for the namespace http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http.
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.DestinationFactoryManagerImpl.getDestinationFactory(DestinationFactoryManagerImpl.java:130)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.initDestination(ServerImpl.java:78)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.(ServerImpl.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:159)
    ... 2 more

If I browse the sample-service-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar I can navigate to /org/apache/cxf/transport(s) as well as find any of the classes in the dependent jars.

Comment: That error is a result of missing the JAR file `cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.11.jar` from your classpath.  Is the assembly plugin including that dependency correctly?  You might also want to provide detail on how you are executing it from the command line.

Comment: Updated post. I'm not sure why I get a different error adding the transport jar to the classpath directly, the classes inside the transport jar are in my bundled jar.

Comment: Now I believe you are missing the embedded HTTP server dependency.  Are you using Jetty?  Then it would be cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-2.7.11.jar.  You seem to have a problem in the test-service-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar file.  How are the dependencies added to the jar by Maven?  You might also want to post the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF from that jar.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've put up a new project with all the poms and the service impl and manifest.

Comment: I am not familiar enough with the Maven `jar-with-dependencies` feature to be of any more help.  It might be helpful to ask a new question about that feature, as I think its the key issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was that the cxf classes needed to be set on the classpath even though they were bundled into my jar... Didn't make sense why but that was the fix.

Comment: Could you add details on the procedure to follow to solve the problem ? Thanks.

Comment: @matthieusb Any updates on the procedure to solve the issue ?

Comment: So what exactly is now the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Seems classloader changes from using manifest than from using `java -cp`

Here is the different:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-core/2.7.17/org/apache/cxf/bus/extension/ExtensionManagerImpl.java#164

with classpath, Classloader finds several jars with `META-INF/cxf/bus-extensions.txt` but with manifest only cxf-core (which don't have that http transport defined)